# Виртуальные хосты в апаче. Не открывать неопределенные в конфиге поддомены

Tags: apache, httpd, virtual-hosts

Приветствую.

1 IP, на нем N хостов. 
Описаны как виртуальные хосты, записи в httpd.conf вот такого вида:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
ServerAlias otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Столкнулся с тем, что при попытке открыть неопределенный в конфиге поддомен, к примеру, ns2.domain.tld, открывается содержимое domain.tld. Но в servername, serveralias этот поддомен не фигурирует. Как запретить открывать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последний определённый `VirtualHost` является виртхостом по умолчанию, в него попадают все запросы, для которых не нашлось подходящего виртхоста (наверное, можно как-то явно задать дефолтный виртуалхост, но я не знаю как).

Соответственно, нужно создать служебный VirtualHost, который будет подцепляться последним (например, стоять последним в конфиге) и разместить в нём какую-нибудь заглушку.

Answer (score 1):

В конце допишите:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

Это будет возвращать 404 на все несуществующие хосты.

Comment: не помогло.

Comment: А не стоит ли поверх Apache фронтендом, например, nginx? Тогда он, получая 404, может делать что-то ещё своё – напр. показывать дефолтный сайт.